# Counting number of months; is the number of months with more than 2000 transactions greater than 3

Tags: sql

I want to count the number of months with more than 2000 transactions. 
I now have counted the number of transactions per month but how can I add the extra condition?
This is the query I have now:

```
select 
run_date, count(1) as Number_Of_Transactions
from 
transactions
where
run_date = '08-10-19' 
or
run_date = '08-9-19' 
or 
run_date = '08-8-19' 
or
run_date = '08-7-19'   
or
run_date = '08-6-19'   
or
run_date = '08-5-19'
group by 
run_date
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: Tag your qustion with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you sure this are transactions per month you are counting ?

Comment: Note that something like `WHERE foo = 'a' OR foo = 'b' OR foo = 'c'` can be simplified to `WHERE foo IN ('a', 'b', 'c')`

Comment: Database Im using is Oracle

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried the following:
select count(*)
from (select year(run_date) as yyyy, month(run_date) as mm,
      count(*) as num_transactions
      from transactions
      group by year(run_date), month(run_date)
      having count(*)>1
      ) ym;

But I get the following error message:
ORA-00904: "MONTH": ongeldige ID
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 118 Column: 32

Do you have any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You would use two levels of aggregation.  Date functions are notoriously database dependent, but something like this:

```
select count(*)
from (select year(run_date) as yyyy, month(run_date) as mm,
             count(*) as num_transactions
      from transactions
      group by year(run_date), month(run_date)
      having count(*) > 2000
     ) ym
```

Comment: I'm amazed that `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` can be applied [in SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dd978b39648214b955a126518f7be2fe) to strings such as `08-10-19`

Comment: in [MySQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r3YRZ4gBZHaboUrF2NL8xd/0) this provides wrong results, however

Comment: @Cid I believe that the conversion was made from string to date and then a year or month function is done... It can not be done to the strings that do not meet all  date format conditions.